# Line Count ForEach-Object on multiple files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate a line count that gets added to each file for a loop.  The count needs to be put into the footer of each file as it checks it.  Another concern is that the count needs to include the addition of the header and footer lines (i.e. 8 lines + 1 header + 1 footer = 10).  My code I'm using is below and I know that the code to count the lines is `Get-Content $mypath | Measure-Object -Line | {$linecount = $_.Count}` but I dont know how to properly incorporate it.  Any suggestions?

```
Get-ChildItem $destinationfolderpath -REcurse -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object -Begin { $seq = 0 } -Process {
        $seq++ 
        $seq1 = "{0:D4}" -f $seq; $header="File Sequence Number $seq1"
        $footer="File Sequence Number $seq1 and Line Count $looplinecount"
        $header + "`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) + $footer | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So load the content of the file to a variable within the loop, perform your `measure -line` on that variable, add 2 (one of the header line, one for the footer line), and drop that into a sub-expression for the footer...

```
Get-ChildItem $destinationfolderpath -REcurse -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object -Begin { $seq = 0 } -Process {
    $seq++
    $seq1 = "{0:D4}" -f $seq
    $header="File Sequence Number $seq1"
    $Content=Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String
    $footer="File Sequence Number $seq1 and Line Count $(($content|measure -line|select -expand lines)+2)"
    "$header`n$Content$footer" | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but wouldnt `measure -line|select -expand count` need to be `measure -line|select -expand lines`

Comment: I was just using the OP's code for it in essence, I didn't even second guess it. I just edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: Works great, thank you!  I still have to figure out how to format the $Content into the "{0:D4}" -f like in $seq1, but that's much more manageable.